# Implement GraphQL & Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, graphql

Is there a way to implement GraphQL in flutter?
I was trying making the API call with the query and variables objects in a JSON object.

type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/graphql_flutter) package for a few weeks now and it seems to work well enough. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart' show Client, InMemoryCache;
...
Future<dynamic> post(
    String body, {
    Map<String, dynamic> variables,
  }) async {
    final Client client = Client(
      endPoint: endpoint,
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    );

    final Future<Map<String, dynamic>> result =
        client.query(query: body, variables: variables);

    return result;
  }
```

To use just give it the graphql and any variables. i.e. a delete mutation may look like

```
String deleteMutation =
      '''mutation deleteItem(\$itemId: ID!) {
    deleteItem(input: { itemId: \$itemId}) {
      itemId
    }
  }'''.replaceAll('\n', ' ');

 await post(deleteMutation , variables: <String, dynamic>{'itemId': itemId});
```

Comment: Does that need await async in methods?

Comment: sorry forgot to add.

Comment: woudln't this make your life easier to use `.gql` files for graphql queries? As you'd have syntax tooling.

Comment: @aqwert will your graphql client gets created for every post request?

Answer (score 0):

This is updated and working solution of @aqwert

```
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';
...

HttpLink link = HttpLink(uri: /*your url here*/); // you can also use headers for authorization etc. 
GraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient(link: link as Link, cache: InMemoryCache());

QueryOptions query = QueryOptions(
    document:
    r'''
      mutation deleteItem($id: String!) {
        deleteItem(callId: $id)
      }
    ''',
    variables: {'id' : id}
);

var result = await client.query(query);
```