# Flutter GraphQl client cache

Tags: flutter, graphql, flutter-graphql

I am using Flutter [graphql_client](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter) which implemented pretty much as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838261/2237148)

My client creation looks like this:

```
abstract class AbstractAdapter {
  Link get httpLink;

 GraphQLClient client;

 AbstractAdapter() {
   client = GraphQLClient(cache: InMemoryCache(), link: httpLink);
 }

 Future<QueryResult> query(QueryOptions options) {
   return client.query(options);
 }
}
```

It works pretty well but the problem is with the caching
If I send the same mutation twice, it returns the cached result instead of sending it again!

Appreciates any help.

Answer (score 5):

you must use  FetchPolicy.networkOnly in QueryOptions and MutationOptions , fetchPolicy property

```
      String query, Map<String, dynamic> variables) async {
    QueryOptions options = QueryOptions(
        documentNode: gql(query),
        variables: variables,
        fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.networkOnly);

    final result = await _client.query(options);

    return result;
  }

Future<QueryResult> performMutation(
      String query, Map<String, dynamic> variables) async {
    MutationOptions options = MutationOptions(
        documentNode: gql(query),
        variables: variables,
        fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.networkOnly);

    final result = await _client.mutate(options);
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem,
I was trying to send mutation on a query api, this will return the last cached response which is not good for mutation.

I've added mutation query with MutationOptions to my GraphQL adapter like this:

```
abstract class AbstractAdapter {
Link get httpLink;

GraphQLClient client;

AbstractAdapter() {
  client = GraphQLClient(cache: InMemoryCache(), link: httpLink);
}

Future<QueryResult> query(QueryOptions options) {
  return client.query(options);
 }

Future<QueryResult> mutate(MutationOptions options) {
  return client.mutate(options);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use FetchPolicy.networkOnly or updateCache after mutation is completed.